# Android button text align change when view.GONE is changed to view.VISIBLE

Tags: android, text, button, android-layout, android-button

I have something like "custom list view" but it's just several table layouts in another table layout and all wrapped in one big `ScrollView`.

`onClick` method on one of the tables I expand it by `label.setVisibility` and `button.setvisibility` to `view.VISIBLE` and change `onClickListener`.

The problem occurs when I expand for instance 2 tables the text on button suddenly goes to left. No android:gravity or custom text formatting from HTML didn't helped.

Any ideas?

Figure 1: opened first

[image: Figure 1 : opened first]

Figure 2: opened second

[image: Figure 2 : opened second]

code for buttons & onClickListener for Table (NOT BUTTON!!)

```
        private TableRow PrepareAdditionalInfoButton(int id) {
            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(ClassX.this);
            tableRow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            Button button = new Button(ClassX.this);
            button.setText("Odborné informace");
            LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
            layoutParams.leftMargin = 20;
            layoutParams.rightMargin = 20;
            button.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            button.setId(id + 2000);
            button.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
            tableRow.addView(button);
            return tableRow;
    }
```

table onClickListener:

```
        public View.OnClickListener showDetail = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int id = view.getId();
            View additionalInfo = findViewById(id + 1000);
            additionalInfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            View additionalInfoButton = findViewById(id + 2000);
            additionalInfoButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view.setOnClickListener(closeDetail);
    }
};
```

Comment: have you tried setting the gravity of the button to center?

Comment: ehm.... "No android:gravity or custom text formatting from HTML didn't helped."

Comment: try adding 
button.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL); before button.setId(id + 2000);